# Calculating the Month-life Column

Tags: sql-server

I have a weird requirement to build a table with a derived calculation column based on the values of the first two columns. This is a kind of matrix

```
MonthID Actmon  RegMonthNo  MOnthlife
201001  1         1          (Actmon-Regmon)+1
201002  2         2
201003  3         3
201004  4         4
201005  5         5
201006  6         6
201007  7         7
201008  8         8
201009  9         9
201010  10       10
201011  11       11
```

so if Regmonth=6 and activemonth10.. then monthlife Row=(10-6)+1 =5

But donno how to desing this table as it changes based on the registrationRow and Activitymo row

Comment: May you explain how (Actmon - RegMonthNo) + 1 wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Add a computed column to your table:

```
CREATE TABLE
        mytable
        (
        monthid DATE PRIMARY KEY,
        actmon INT,
        regMonthNo INT,
        monthLife AS actmon - regmon + 1
        )
```

See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7535f/1